# Xcode 9.2 - “Fixed Width Constraints May Cause Clipping” Warning

Tags: ios, storyboard, constraints

I am facing this problem for the constraints added to the labels in the storyboard. I have read to change the "fixed length" to ">=" or "<=".
But what does ">=" or "<=" mean on Label constraints and which one should I use ?

Comment: Can you able to share your added constraints and what you want to achieve. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning says that if label got bigger text than rest of text will cut which does not fit in fixed width.

>= Means the width of the label will become flexible if label got bigger text; the minimum width will be the one you have set.

<= Means the maximum width of the label will be the one you set.

More convenient way to set label constraints is to set leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints instead of setting width constraint where, trailing space will have >= constraints with the value for minimum space required between parent view and label / horizontally near by view and label.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, this explains a lot.

Comment: Happy Coding :)